# scale-out signalr server with redis backplane not working correctly (vue front end)

Tags: c#, vue.js, websocket, signalr

**Appreciation for any answers!**

I created a signalr backend server based on .net core 3.1 running on docker(debian).
It works well when i only create single server deployment on kubernetes.
But when i increase replicas to more than 1 ,it works incorrectly.
It looks like the redis backplane not working ,and leads to unreachable communication between multiple servers .

**Following the official documention,i installed nuget package:**

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.StackExchangeRedis" Version="3.1.13" />
```

**this is the backend server startup.cs code :**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
// ...
  services
    .AddSignalR(option =>
    {
        option.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
    })
    .AddNewtonsoftJsonProtocol()
    .AddStackExchangeRedis(option =>
    {
    option.ConnectionFactory = async writer =>
    {
        var config = new ConfigurationOptions
        {
            AbortOnConnectFail = false,
            ChannelPrefix = "devopshub",
            ServiceName = "devopshub",
            ClientName = "devopshub"
        };
        config.DefaultDatabase = 13;
        var connection = await ConnectionMultiplexer.ConnectAsync("redis host:6379,allowAdmin=true,defaultdatabase=13", writer);
        connection.ConnectionFailed += (_, e) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("SignalR Redis Server Connection Failed.");
        };
        if (connection.IsConnected)
            Console.WriteLine("SignalR Redis Server Connected.");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("SignalR Redis Server Not Connected.");
        return connection;
    };
// ... 
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
// ...
    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseCors(builder => builder
    .SetIsOriginAllowed(_ => true)
    .AllowAnyMethod()
    .AllowAnyHeader()
    .AllowCredentials());
    app.UseEndpoints(builder =>
    {
        builder.MapHub<LogHub>("/api/loghub").RequireCors(t => t.SetIsOriginAllowed(_ => true).AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader().AllowCredentials());
        builder.MapHub<ProcessDetailStatusSyncHub>("/api/processdetailstatussynchub").RequireCors(t => t.SetIsOriginAllowed(_ => true).AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader().AllowCredentials());
        builder.MapControllers();
        builder.MapHealthChecks("/health");
    });
// ...
}
```

All codes seems ok,and it does work correctly when the server is deployed single.once i add the replicas ,the websocket connection would reset or disconnect immediately or after several seconds.
After that,the front end (vue)project would throw an unhandle error ,and then it would crash.

**Like this:**

```
Error: read ECONNRESET
    at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:205:27)
Emitted 'error' event on Socket instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:92:8)
    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:60:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
  errno: 'ECONNRESET',
  code: 'ECONNRESET',
  syscall: 'read'
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! frontendProjectName@0.0.1 dev: `vue-cli-service serve`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the frontendProjectName@0.0.1 dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-03-18T03_13_05_435Z-debug.log
终端进程“C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -Command npm run dev”已终止，退出代码: 1。
```

*The last line chinese words means"process stoped, exit with code 1"*

**And this is the log file content :**

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'D:\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'D:\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'dev'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.13.4
3 info using node@v12.16.1
4 verbose run-script [ 'predev', 'dev', 'postdev' ]
5 info lifecycle frontendProjectName@0.0.1~predev: frontendProjectName@0.0.1
6 info lifecycle frontendProjectName@0.0.1~dev: frontendProjectName@0.0.1
7 verbose lifecycle frontendProjectName@0.0.1~dev: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle frontendProjectName@0.0.1~dev: PATH: D:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;E:\workspace\CICD\hualv-devops-frontend\node_modules\.bin;C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\ProgramData\DockerDesktop\version-bin;C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin;C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DTS\Binn\;D:\Program Files\platform-tools;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin;D:\nodejs\;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn\;E:\Nuget;C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;D:\Program Files\Fiddler;D:\Docker Toolbox;C:\Users\ASUS\.dotnet\tools;D:\JetBrains Rider\bin;;D:\Microsoft VS Code\bin;E:\Nuget;C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Fiddler;C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;D:\JetBrains Rider 2020.3.2\bin;
9 verbose lifecycle frontendProjectName@0.0.1~dev: CWD: E:\workspace\CICD\hualv-devops-frontend
10 silly lifecycle frontendProjectName@0.0.1~dev: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'vue-cli-service serve' ]
11 silly lifecycle frontendProjectName@0.0.1~dev: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle frontendProjectName@0.0.1~dev: Failed to exec dev script
13 verbose stack Error: frontendProjectName@0.0.1 dev: `vue-cli-service serve`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (D:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:311:20)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (D:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:311:20)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:286:5)
14 verbose pkgid frontendProjectName@0.0.1
15 verbose cwd E:\workspace\CICD\hualv-devops-frontend
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19041
17 verbose argv "D:\\nodejs\\node.exe" "D:\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "dev"
18 verbose node v12.16.1
19 verbose npm  v6.13.4
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error frontendProjectName@0.0.1 dev: `vue-cli-service serve`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the frontendProjectName@0.0.1 dev script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

**And the server console log something like this:**

```
Socket connection closed prematurely.
System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketException (0x80004005): The remote party closed the WebSocket connection without completing the close handshake.
 ---> System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketException (0x80004005): The remote party closed the WebSocket connection without completing the close handshake.
   at System.Net.WebSockets.ManagedWebSocket.ThrowIfEOFUnexpected(Boolean throwOnPrematureClosure)
   at System.Net.WebSockets.ManagedWebSocket.EnsureBufferContainsAsync(Int32 minimumRequiredBytes, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean throwOnPrematureClosure)
   at System.Net.WebSockets.ManagedWebSocket.ReceiveAsyncPrivate[TWebSocketReceiveResultGetter,TWebSocketReceiveResult](Memory`1 payloadBuffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken, TWebSocketReceiveResultGetter resultGetter)
   at System.Net.WebSockets.ManagedWebSocket.ReceiveAsyncPrivate[TWebSocketReceiveResultGetter,TWebSocketReceiveResult](Memory`1 payloadBuffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken, TWebSocketReceiveResultGetter resultGetter)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Internal.Transports.WebSocketsServerTransport.StartReceiving(WebSocket socket)
```

Comment: I have tries all solutions i found ,but all turnd to no use.I have monitored redis io with redis-cli monitor ,and i found no io record.So i guess the reason is redis backplane not working makes multiple server signalr communication not reachable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay,all is my fault.After carefully read the official documention again ,i found out the reason .I ignored the last one point:

[**Configure your server farm load balancing software for sticky sessions.**](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/aspnet/core/signalr/redis-backplane?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

The solution for my situation is to configure nginx ingress to enable **Sticky Session**,like this:

```
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity: cookie
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity-mode: balanced
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-expires: "86400"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-max-age: "86400"
```

*Add config above to **metadata:annotations** node in ingress yaml*

Comment: Thanks for everyone viewed this question.